# alternative to the fscanf()/vscanf() functions family for using an alternative validation key or how to create a custom language layout?

Tags: c, keyboard, embedded, dos, turbo-c

I am rather knew in C. And the only way I know for setting a variable from stdin is by using the`fscanf()`/`vscanf()`functions family.

DOS operating systems are seeing a resurgence in the embedded market. The device which I am using is programmatically compatible with DOS and use a NEC V30Mx which feature the 80286 instruction set.
The problem is the built-in keyboard doesn’t feature the enter key and instead use the EXE key which enter the 0x1C00 key code *([Alt enter](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/README_GRUB4DOS.txt))*.

So when I write a program like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dir.h>
#include <dos.h>
int main(void) {
    int res, number = 0;
    printf("int value?");
    res = scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("The value is %d", number);
    return;
}
```

`scanf()`is called and "`int value?`" is displayed on the screen. I can write numbers and upercase letters. but I can’t validate the output since nothing feature the [0x1C0D key code](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/README_GRUB4DOS.txt), and the EXE key use a different keycode.
Of course C has no knowledge of keyboard but the C standard library binaries look for the [0x1C0D key code](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/README_GRUB4DOS.txt) for entering a`\n`.

So is there an alternative to the`fscanf()`/`vscanf()`functions family which is part of the C standard library?

## Update :

I thought most C standard libraries under dos use software implementation for doing this.
I saw [a DOS call](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2783.htm) for reading files and of course, using the number 0 cause to read from stdin.
So I assembled [this example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/113058), loaded it on the calculator and find myself surprised the manufacturer preferred handling the issue in it’s built-in software rather than fixing the OS... :-( *(I got the the same previous result)*

## Update

I didn’t thought about it but thanks to the comments, I forgot keyboard languages do key code remapping.
So, creating a custom mapping for the qwerty keyboard would be an another way to solve the problem.

Comment: C has no concept of *key* codes, only strings and characters. You have to use OS specific functionality to read scan-/key-codes.

Comment: So your issue is you cannot enter a new-line, a `\n`, a `10`, a `0x0A`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Heemmm, the manufacturer feature utilities for transferring programs to the device from a PC to the device, but it doesn’t feature any kind of SDK. The operating system is compatible with MS-DOS 5.0. But as far I know using the return key is used to validate`scanf()` input on all implementations.

Comment: @alk : Yes, because the EXE key *(which is the equivalent of the return key)* doesn’t return the same keycode. And the turbo-c C standard library look for the [0x1C0D key code](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/README_GRUB4DOS.txt) for entering a`\n`/`Ox0A`. This require software keyboard remapping *(but I have  no knowledge in x86 assembler)*. The alternative is to tell the input should be ended with an another character.

Comment: If you can't use the standard library to read your target platforms keys, then you can't use the standard library, it's as simple as that. However it's a trivial task to read scan-codes in DOS, it's been solved since very long. Use your favorite search-engine to search for it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : no, everything works`prinft() free() alloc() fopen() fgetc() isspace() fclose() time()..`and as I said in the question, even scanf() near work : the only problem come from the return key. And the solution your are describing isn’t as trivial as reading scan codes in DOS. It requires stopping and setting interrupts for resuming when a key is pressed. It requires an amount of code for managing the arrows and DEL keys. But I guess there is an alternative in the C standard library for the`fscanf()`/`vscanf()`functions family which would allow to use an alternate validation char.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Of course, I also read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API). But the API is for assembler.

Comment: Do you have a library function `getch()`? If so, what is the (numeric) value that your "Enter" key returns? `scanf()` is a pretty horrible (opinion, sorry) function to use, can't you make your own input function?

Comment: @WeatherVane : Yes of course, it is CONIO.H, I already tried it and it return no known char.  However there are lot of of software created in the 90’s for playing with the key codes of the keyboard. I already wrote the result in my question : the exe key return the [0x1C00](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/README_GRUB4DOS.txt). Building my own input function would mean spending a lot of time : write assembly for setting keyboard interrupts and puting the CPU execution to idle. you need to manage  arrows and DEL keys. handle newlines when the text reach the top right of the screen.

Comment: This is a `C` and `embedded` question. You didn't mention anything about assembler or screen handling. Does your DOS implementation use code pages? Would that solve it?

Comment: @WeatherVane : I mentioned the Development software I try to use in the tags : TurboC 3.0. And yes, I didn’t talked about the OS, it is [ROM-DOS](http://www.datalight.com/products/rom-dos) form datalight. I don’t know anything about code pages. The normal user doesn’t know the calculator is powered by DOS and all the filesystems are hidden. The programs are transfered with a proprietary protocol from the manufacturer over RS-232. When a program is added an additional icon is added on the start-up screen. There is no command prompt. But I guess there is no code pages.

Comment: This doc from ROM-DOS talks about mapping the keyboard layout using code pages. Whether making an appropriate code page is more work than altering the keyboard interrupt, I don't know. http://www.rtd.com/NEW_manuals/software/cpumodules/ROMDOS_manual.pdf

Comment: @WeatherVane : Anyway, creating a custom language keyboard layout looks to be a very good idea. But I don’t know do it. Also I can’t run COM files. only DOS-MZ executable format is available for custom apps. Also I’m using an old ROM-DOS version which was created in 1999. It doesn’t use a kernel 7.1 or 6.0 kernel but a [lower version](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casio_Graph_100%2B).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `scanf` does not read past the bytes present in stdin that represent the `EXE` key.

Can you investigate to see what actual characters are read by `getchar()` when you press the `EXE` key, and write a function `hasexe()` that skips these if present.  Call this function before or after the `scanf()`.

Also check `scanf()` return value and check for `EOF`.

Comment: The EXE key doesn’t return any characters. However, as I said in my question, pressing it return the 0x1C00 key code, which correspond to pressing [Alt+enter](http://diddy.boot-land.net/grub4dos/files/README_GRUB4DOS.txt) key combination on a real PC running DOS with a real keyboard. but there are no key which can return the 0x1C0D keycode which correspond to real return key.

Comment: @user2284570: A *key* does not *return* characters.  My question is: does pressing the `EXE` key cause characters to be available in `stdin`.  If it does not, you need to read the input with a lower level set of functions and store  characters in a buffer, then parse this buffer with `sscanf()` or simpler functions.

Comment: pressing Alt+Enter doesn’t cause characters to be written on the screen on most systems. But before going to a lower level, I guess the C standard library, or the C DOS standard library provide an alternative to the fscanf()/vscanf() functions family.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve such a problem with standard C library is to use getchar() (or fgetc() on stdin) to get a character one at a time, detect the EXE key yourself, NUL terminate the string and pass it to sscanf().

Comment: and manage were characters are printed on the screen because of the delete key which also managing the newlines adding/deletion. Manage the actions of arrows key. Which mean writing assembler for a large part. I also disagree about [the way you describe is the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14494309/2284570#comment46699604_14495579)

Comment: The standard C library doesn't define how where the characters are printed on the screen, nor actions of arrow keys. In my experience, scanf() and getchar() behave the same in that regard in many standard C library implementations (because scanf() actually calls getchar() or equivalent function). Keep in mind that this is getchar(), not the non-standard-yet-often-available getch(). Also, from the link you provided I don't see what is the other standard C library approach to solve this?

Comment: `The standard C library doesn't define how where the characters are printed on the screen, nor actions of arrow keys`but as I said in my question the implementations do. In the link I provided if I would use that code then pressing tab would cause`scanf()`returning. The problem is I don‘t know how to use direct integer conversion with that kind of expression.

Comment: Well, your question was about a function from the standard library that is the alternative, not from the standard library _implementation_ you use (and you didn't specify which one you use). I actually remember solving a similar problem with getchar() in a DOS program some 20 years ago with some version of Borland/Turbo C. So, I recommend you try it out. Also, you didn't specify that we can be creative, like requiring a tab instead/after EXE. For example, the ioctl() call is from the POSIX standard and available in most DOS toolchains, and you may be able to make use of it.

Comment: Part of "solving the guy problem not answering his question". Except that I bought the device because it’s built-in software present things unavailable on the software market for PC and tablets. The fact that it run on a DOS instead of bare metal Super-Hitach or zilog 80 was an another factor too. I was also needing more functionalities than the built-in software provides in all cases. So I chose a device with DOS and vendor supplied programs for transferring softwares.

Comment: I just found an implementation for[`ah=0ah int 21h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm). However I have troubles at understanding how I can modify [this function](http://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/svn/HEAD/tree/kernel/trunk/kernel/chario.c#l360).